# WebAPI route not found when using ApiController.Url inside HttpServer

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2013, xunit.net, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have few integration tests that was working correctly with Web API 1, after I have upgraded to Web API 2 (5.0) they are not working and giving me the null reference when calling the following code:

```
string uri = Url.Link(HttpRouteConstants.RouteName, new { param1 =
paramValue1, param2 = paramValue2 });
```

Basically the *Url.Link* can't find the route (at least I think this is the problem). I think that problem is with the way *HttpConfiguration* & routes are being registered in the Web API 2. We had to change the *WebApiConfig* registration call

from

```
WebApiConfig.Register(config)
```

to

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
```

and now when using the integration test setup, where I'm providing the *HttpServer* with *HttpConfiguration* instance I can't call something like *GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);* but I'm using the old way and doing the following *WebApiConfig.Register(config)* which doesn't seems to work correctly. FYI my routing configs are placed in the WebApiConfig.

Does anyone know any workarounds ?

This is the stack I'm using:

- VS 2013 (.NET 4.5.1)
- WebAPI 2 (convention-based routing & attribute routing)
- xUnit
- Ninject

**Update**

Here is the integration test code sample

```
// Create configuration
HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

config.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;            
config.DependencyResolver = new NinjectDependencyResolver(Kernel);

//WebApiConfig.Register(config); Below is the excerpt from WebApiConfig
config.EnableCors((System.Web.Http.Cors.ICorsPolicyProvider)config.DependencyResolver.GetService(typeof(System.Web.Http.Cors.ICorsPolicyProvider)));

config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: HttpRouteConstants.ApplicationAPIRouteName,
    routeTemplate: CoreRouteConstants.DefaultApplicationControllerRoute + "/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: HttpRouteConstants.DefaultAPIRouteName,
    routeTemplate: CoreRouteConstants.DefaultControllerRoute + "/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);


HttpServer server = null;
try
{
  server = new HttpServer(config);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  throw ex;
}

string controller = String.Format("{0}{1}/api/MyController/{2}/", HttpServerBaseAddress, param1, param2);
var client = new HttpClient(Server);
using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.DeleteAsync(controller, new CancellationTokenSource().Token).Result)
{
    response.IsSuccessStatusCode.Should().BeFalse();
    response.StatusCode.Should().Be(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
}

//Below is the code from MyController
public virtual async Task<HttpResponseMessage> DeleteAsync([FromUri]object key)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = null;
    HttpStatusCode statusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
    bool result = await Store.DeleteAsync(key);
    if (!result)
        statusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
    response = Request.CreateResponse<bool>(statusCode, result);
    string uri = Url.Link(HttpRouteConstants.ApplicationAPIRouteName, new { param1 = "param1", id = key });
    //NOTE: uri is null here as I mentioned 
    response.Headers.Location = new Uri(uri);
    return response;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Could you share how your integration test looks like? I have tried an integration test scenario at my end where I am able to generate links, so I am curious as to how your code looks like. In my scenario I haven't used Ninject though.

`GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);` makes sure to call `HttpConfiguration.EnsureInitialized()` *after* all the Web API configuration is done.

So if you are calling `WebApiConfig.Register` in your integration test, you can try calling `HttpConfiguration.EnsureInitialized()` *after* the Web API configuration is done and see if this fixes the issue.

Comment: I'm unable to find the 'HttpConfiguration.ConfigureInitialized()', can you let me know if this is an extension method and where to find it ? Thanks

Comment: My bad...i meant EnsureInitialized extension on HttpConfiguration

Comment: Ahh, sorry I didn't see that ... I have tried _EnsureInitialized_ but error is still there so I suppose that they have an issue in the _HttpServer_ & _Url.Link_